# Symfony2 form datetime fields validation

Tags: forms, symfony, datetime

In my form I have two `datetime` fields: `startDate` and `endDate`. `startDate` can't be earlier than current time. `endDate` cant be earlier or equal to the `startDate` and it can't be more than one month from the `startDate`.

So my question is how I could implement validation for those fields? I'm pretty new to Symfony so I would really appreciate if you could add and example of it.

My form:

```
<?php
namespace Atotrukis\MainBundle\Form\Type;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;
class CreateEventFormType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('name', 'text', [
                'constraints' =>[
                    new Assert\NotBlank([
                        'message' => "Renginio pavadinimas negali būti tuščias"
                    ]),
                    new Assert\Length([
                        'min' => "2",
                        'max' => "255",
                        'minMessage' => "Renginio pavadinimas negali būti trumpesnis nei {{ limit }} simboliai",
                        'maxMessage' => "Renginio pavadinimas negali būti ilgesnis nei {{ limit }} simboliai"
                    ])
                ]
            ])
            ->add('description', 'textarea', [
                'constraints' =>[
                    new Assert\NotBlank([
                        'message' => "Renginio aprašymas negali būti tuščias"
                    ]),
                    new Assert\Length([
                        'min' => "10",
                        'max' => "5000",
                        'minMessage' => "Renginio aprašymas negali būti trumpesnis nei {{ limit }} simbolių",
                        'maxMessage' => "Renginio aprašymas negali būti ilgesnis nei {{ limit }} simbolių"
                    ])
                ]
            ])
            ->add('startDate', 'datetime')
            ->add('endDate', 'datetime')
            ->add('map', 'text')
            ->add('city', 'entity', array(
                'class' => 'AtotrukisMainBundle:City',
                'property' => 'name',
                'constraints' =>[
                    new Assert\NotBlank([
                        'message' => "Pasirinkite miestą"
                    ])
                ],
                'empty_value' => 'Pasirinkite miestą',
                'query_builder' => function(EntityRepository $er) {
                    return $er->createQueryBuilder('c')
                        ->addOrderBy('c.priority', 'ASC')
                        ->addOrderBy('c.name', 'ASC');
                },
            ))
            ->add('save', 'submit', array('label' => 'Sukurti'));
    }
    public function getName()
    {
        return 'createEventForm';
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can think of two ways you can acchive what you ask.

First way is Create a Class Constraint Validator. You can follow my answer on a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16834037/1424951) and the chapter on the sf2 documentation [here](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/validation/custom_constraint.html)

Second way is to make use of [Callback](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/constraints/Callback.html) Constraint. For example in you CreateEventFormType class:

```
public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
{
    $resolver->setDefaults(array(
        'constraints'=> 
              array(new Callback(array('methods'=>array(array($this, 'customFormValidation'))))),
    ));
}

public function customFormValidation($data, ExecutionContextInterface $context)
{
    if ($data['startDate'] && $data['endDate'] && $data['startDate'] > $data['endDate']) {
        $context->addViolationAt('startDate', 'your constraint message here');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

SF3/Silex2 update (I know the question is for SF2)
this code is for Silex but the only differences are the builder factory function and the render stuff.

```
    $form = $app->namedForm('form', $data, [
        'constraints' => array(
            new Callback(function ($data, ExecutionContextInterface $context) {
                if ($data['to'] && $data['from'] && $data['to'] < $data['from']) {
           $context->buildViolation('error')->addViolation();
                }
            }),
        ),
    ])
        ->add('from', DateType::class)
        ->add('to', DateType::class)
        ->add('save', SubmitType::class)
        ->getForm();

    $form->handleRequest($request);

    if ($form->isSubmitted()) {

        if ($form->isValid()) {
            // your submit stuff
            return $app->redirect($request->getUri());
        }
        // error validation does not dispay errors after a redirect
    }

    return $app['twig']->render('form.html.twig', [
        'form' => $form->createView(),
    ]);
```